# PreProcessInterceptor for jersey

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, resteasy

`RestEasy` provides a `PreProcessInterceptor` using which you can **intercept** incoming request to your web-service and then you can check things like **which method** will be invoked in-response to this request accordingly you can decide to let it pass or return a response.

I'm developing a web service using jersey **is there any similar class or something** in jersey using which i can intercept incoming requests and check details?

Currently i'm using a `Filter` to capture the requests and do stuff but i want a better approach.

Comment: Which Jersey do you have in mind (1.x vs 2.x)? What is your use-case - is there something that `ContainerRequestFilter` does not offer and `PreProcessInterceptor` does?

Comment: @michal.gajdos I want reference of the Method which the request will be mapped to. for e.g GET Users\ will be mapped to getUsers(), how can i get reference to the method

Comment: @MichalGajdos I am using Jersey 1.X and I had the same question. What would you recommend in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the following, filter the events as needed:

[RequestEventListener](http://jersey.java.net/apidocs/snapshot/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/monitoring/RequestEventListener.html#onEvent%28org.glassfish.jersey.server.monitoring.RequestEvent%29)

Answer (score 1):

In Jersey 2.x you can retrieve resource method via:

- [ContainerRequestContext](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html) which is passed into the filters `ContainerRequestFilter#filter(ContainerRequestContext)` method:

  ```
  ((ExtendedUriInfo) containerRequestContext.getUriInfo()).getMatchedResourceMethod()
  ```
- injecting [ExtendedUriInfo](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ExtendedUriInfo.html) into your filter (and call `#getMatchedResourceMethod()`):

  ```
  @Inject
  private ExtendedUriInfo extendedUriInfo;
  ```

**Note**: Your filters cannot be annotated with `@PreMatching` annotation since the matching informations are not available at this moment.

Comment: Do you know if we can use ContainerRequestFilter in Jersey 1.X for the same purpose? Please advice. Thanks.